# What is the difference between the "Write" and "Write+" modes on an APC SNMP card?

Tags: permissions, snmp, ups, apc

I'm configuring a UPS to be controllable via SNMP and have come across to options:

- `Write` mode
- `Write+` mode

I've tested both settings and only `Write+` works for me so it's what I'll have to use. I'm interested to know what exactly `Write+` enables as opposed to just the regular `Write` mode though.

[image: mode selection page]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A user with `write+` access can issue SNMP writes when another user is logged into the web interface, a user with `write` cannot. SNMP reads are unaffected.

Comment: Thank you so much, I've just tested this against an AP9617 card and you're absolutely right.

Answer (score 0):

from the PDU HELP:

> - Read: GETS only, at any time
> - Write: GETS at any time, and SETS when no user is logged onto the Web interface or command line interface.
> - Write+: GETS and SETS at any time.
> - Disable: No GETS or SETS at any time.